# "Mächtigkeit" versus "Kardinalität"?

Tags: set-theory, ho.history-overview

In Cantor's set theory, is there any difference between the terms *Mächtigkeit* and *Kardinalität* ?

Comment: (warning: bad German ahead) Lawvere certainly seems to think that the difference between _Menge_ and _Kardinale_ is one that has been lost https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Cohesive+Toposes+and+Cantor%27s+%22lauter+Einsen%22#overview_of_the_paper . I'm not completely familiar with _Mächtigkeit_ and _Kardinalität_, but I guess the former would be translated 'potency', so that sets (Mengen?) are equipollent when there is an isomorphism between them. The Kardinale associated to a Menge is a different sort of object, and so I guess that's why one could talk of the Kardinalität as something distinct

Comment: Do you mean "to Cantor", when you say "in Cantor's set theory"? Or in the broader sense of set theory as it generally stood at its beginning?

Comment: Looking at your recent questions, it might be worth mentioning that there is also a separate site for [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions). At least some of the [top ho.history-overview answerers on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/tags/ho.history-overview/topusers) have an account also on that site; for example, [Carlo Beenakker](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/users/1697/carlo-beenakker), [Francois Ziegler](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/users/658/francois-ziegler) or [Alexandre Eremenko](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/users/64/alexandre-eremenko).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question just because it would be suited for HSM (not because I think it is a bad question per se)

Answer (score 18):

Here is how Cantor introduced "Mächtigkeiten" in [Ueber eine elementare Frage der Mannigfaltigketislehre](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN37721857X_0001) (1890):

[image]

*The "Mächtigkeiten" represent the unique and necessary generalisation of the finite "Cardinal numbers", they are nothing other than infinitely large Cardinal numbers, and they share the same reality and definiteness.*

So it seems that, at least initially, Cantor did not speak of "Kardinalität", which was linked to the existing term of "cardinal numbers", a term from the 16th century meaning "principal numbers". He introduced a new term "Mächtigkeiten" for infinitely large cardinal numbers. The [dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cardinality) I consulted lists 1935 as the first use of the term "cardinality". Because "Mächtigkeiten" is not easily transferred to the English language, the shift to "Kardinalität" and "cardinality" seems a natural one.

Comment: I recall having seen the word "power" used for the size of infinite sets in an older text, but I can't recall where.

Comment: The natural cognate of "Mächtigkeit" in English is "mightiness", though it seems to have never been used as a translation, "power" being used instead, as pointed out by David Roberts. An example of an old book where it is used is:
https://books.google.dk/books?id=4lTCAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA581&dq=power+of+the+continuum&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjB7MuWx_HcAhXMJlAKHUnGD3wQ6AEIPzAE#v=onepage&q=power%20of%20the%20continuum&f=false
The phrase "power of the continuum" also seems to have lasted a bit longer than "power" as a general term for cardinality.

Comment: There is also "puissance" in French, which can often be seen in old articles by Kuratowski or Sierpinski.

Comment: Yes, "power" is sen in old writings in English.  The power of the real line is $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: The one place (as far as I know) where "power" is still so common in English that "cardinality" would sound strange is the model-theoretic notion of "categoricity in power".

Answer (score 9):

Here is [Cantor's Beiträge zur Begründung der transfiniten Mengenlehre (Erster Artikel)](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PID=GDZPPN00225557X). Read the bottom four lines on the first page: ",Mächtigkeit' oder ,Cardinalzahl' von $M$ nennen wir $\ldots$". That looks a lot like Cantor intended the two to be names for the same concept.
The two lines above that reinforce that idea.

Answer (score 8):

The two terms "Mächtigkeit" and "Kardinalität" do indeed mean [the same](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A4chtigkeit_(Mathematik)) in Cantor's set theory; also today, for instance in lectures in German and Swiss universities, the terms are used as synonyms for the same concept.

Comment: I would feel more confident in your answer if there was a direct quote from Cantor supporting it. The oldest reference on that Wikipedia page is a 1928 set theory text, by which time axiomatic set theory had undergone all kinds of conceptual developments (Zermelo, Skolem, Fraekel, von Neumann etc).